# How to control UI using pyautogui

Tags: python, importerror

I have installed pyautogui in my PC. I my project i entered the code

```
import pyautogui 
im1 = pyautogui.screenshot() 
im1.save('my_screenshot.png') 
im2 = pyautogui.screenshot('my_screenshot2.png')
```

It replies error message as shown below ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:/Users/rkl7cob/Desktop/autoGui.py", line 17, in <module>     
import pyautogui ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

That could happen because your PyAutoGui module isn't updated
`pip install pyautogui --upgrade`